# Validation of viewstate MAC failed.

Tags: asp.net, ssl, visual-studio-2013, viewstate, machinekey

> Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a
>   Web Farm or cluster, ensure that  configuration specifies
>   the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot
>   be used in a cluster

Same question is there in stack overflow and asp.net forum as well, but any of the work around is not fixed my issue.

I am getting above error when I post data from one asp.net page to another page in different web site(hosted in SSL). I have try with adding same machine key in both application and try to give page attribute like below

```
<pages  validateRequest="false" enableEventValidation="false" viewStateEncryptionMode="Never" enableViewStateMac="false" >

 <machineKey validationKey="06E158563F2028028595BDF5943CAE28A95CEA4F" decryptionKey="8DB0D34A423D3C714E548AB4BA80040C789F4E01B9AAE6D27E6363E5DA154702" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />
```

But still I am getting the same error. Please note I am using VS 2013, Latest ASP.net version and Application hosted in SSL.

Please provide a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting in Page directive:

```
<%@ Page 
EnableViewStateMac="false" EnableEventValidation="false" ViewStateEncryptionMode="Never" 
%>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I tried this also. Please check below statement got from MSDN blog, " ASP.NET 4.5.2, the runtime enforces EnableViewStateMac=true. If an application sets <%@ Page EnableViewStateMac="false" %> as a directive or <pages enableViewStateMac="false" /> as a config setting, the runtime ignores it and pretends that the developer had written "true" instead."

Answer (score 0):

I bumped into this issue in a .NET Web application I was moving into a shared hosting environment. In my case, the issue was that ViewState was large enough that it was bumping up against the limit of allocated memory. My suggestion: disable ViewState on Master Pages and Web Forms that don't have any controls that require it. I disabled ViewState on the Master Page and the length of my ViewState dropped from 2800 characters down to 620. Please try this before you go asking for the MachineKey, as so many responses (in a related thread) suggest.